# unable to set database field "email_verified_at" colmun while using gmail login in laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, gmail-api

i have a user system in laravel 8 with laraval fortify auth package. i am adding gmail login to my website and login functionality is working fine but when i add new user via gmail login, i still need to verify user email Id by sending them a verification link. but i want to bypass that option for social login. i am using laravel fortify for authentication and laravel socialite for google login.

here is my SocialLoginController.php code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Auth;

class SocialLoginController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $googleuser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    $user = User::where('email', $googleuser->email)->first();

     if ($user) {
         Auth::login($user);
     } else {
         $username = explode("@",$googleuser->email);
         $date = date("y-m-d H-m-s");
         $user = User::create([
             'name' => $googleuser->name,
             'email' => $googleuser->email,
             'password' => uniqid(),
             'email_verified_at' => $date,
             'username' => $username[0],
         ]);
     }
     return redirect('/dashboard');
}
}
```

Comment: did you add `email_verified_at` to `$fillable` on the Model?

Comment: Still the same, i am getting Null in email_verified_at field. my $date is not saving into this column

Comment: is their any other ways to save current timestemp in to database in laravel?